# Globus installation guide

Tags: globus-toolkit

Is there any good installation guide for Globus toolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 
http://www.globus.org/toolkit/docs/5.0/5.0.2/admin/quickstart

is good and fast.

Answer (score 2):

How about the one from their website? [The Globus Toolkit Installation Guide](http://globus.org/toolkit/docs/3.2/installation/).